# What is the unit decimal digit?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that the unit decimal digit of $k^4$ must be 0, 1, 5,  or  6 for all integers $k$.

This is a homework question of mine, however I have no idea what it is really asking because I have an ebook for the class and it is missing a few pages out of this chapter (just ordered a hard copy).

In the mean time, what is this question asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any decimal numbers can be written in the form $10p+d$, where $d$ is the unit digit. Then by the binomial theorem,

$$(10p+d)^4=(10p)^4+4(10p)^3d+6(10p)d^2+4(10p)d^3+d^4=10q+d^4$$ for some integer $q$.

This shows that only the last digit matters as $10q$ ends in $0$. From there you can conclude.